# Can I see who I voted for?

Tags: support, voting

Is it possible to make a custom query that would show the number of my votes per user/author (of all posts that I voted for)?

Comment: If you really want to, you can write a script that scrapes the `/votes` tab, gathering the PostID of the up- and down- votes you cast. Then use another script to look up the authors via API. Sounds like a lot of work with potential of hitting IP-based throttles.

Comment: Why would you want to know this? Is there something else besides ... wow, that's a nice bunch of numbers? Is there something you want to do with those numbers?

Comment: @Raff, you can process 2000 votes in 67 page-scrapes (no limit) and about 18 API calls (10,000 limit). So this is doable with a scrape+API combo.  It's not "why-able" IMO.

Comment: Sorry, nitpicky edit. ;)

Comment: Web UI, API or SEDE? For API: http://stackapps.com/questions/4725/list-of-votes-by-authenticated-users

Answer (score 13):

You can view your own personal activity on the profile page, but to compile the stats you would have to go through the list manually or perhaps use the API. For example, this should show your upvotes (only YOU can see this link, others would have to substitute their own user IDs)

```
http://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=votes&sort=upvote
```

The [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) does show up/down votes (among others) but only lets you join those votes back to users if the vote type is a `favourite`. So I can see you have favourited 124 questions with this query:

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/252759/which-questions-has-a-user-favourited?UserId=3052751

Comment: I just checked the API Documentation but there doesn't seem to be such an option

Comment: @msrd0 Option for what?

Comment: To see the votes you casted

Comment: Unless you know in advance every question that a user has *viewed*, you cannot get this information from the API.

Comment: Any chance to modify this query to show the answers I voted for, instead of the questions?

Comment: @BrunoAugusto no, it will only work for questions you have favourited.

Comment: @msrd0 impossible on API now: http://stackapps.com/questions/4725/list-of-votes-by-authenticated-users

Answer (score 4):

I've written a short JS you can run on `http://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=votes&sort=upvote` that fetches all your questions and summarizes all the people you voted for and how much.

I didn't run it since not having this information available seems to be intentional but if I get a blessing from SO staff I will gladly release it.

Here is how you can write such a script yourself:

- Create an empty users object.
- Make XHRs to all the pages of `http://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=votes&sort=upvote`
- For each such page, use a query selector to find all links and whether or not you downvoted or upvoted them.
- Make XHRs for each question on the given page, select the author with a selector - if the user id is in the users object increase/decrease it (based on whether or not it was an up/down vote) and if it's not there, set it to zero and then decrease/increase it.
- Once all responses complete (I used promises and $.when.apply since it was already available on SO to detect that) - print the users object.

I am deliberately not releasing the script without blessing since it can make hundreds of requests to SO (which I don't think they mind that much in this scale of a few users) and I did not get a blessing from SO.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not possible.

Votes are secret* so that you can vote on posts without fear or favour. Having this information public would definitely be a bad thing.

While I understand that you want to be able to see how many times you have voted on posts by user X, this still falls under the "votes are secret" thing

<sub>* This isn't strictly true, diamond moderators can see voting trends and developers with database access can see actual votes if they look hard enough, but they're secret to the vast majority of users</sub>

Comment: The way I read the question, the poster was asking about getting statistics on his/her own votes. The votes are not secret to the user who cast the votes. I can see my own votes in my user profile.

Comment: Right, @RetoKoradi I was hoping I could get that statistics for MY votes. There is no ulterior motive behind my question. Just curiosity about distribution of my votes. Perhaps after that I could study more other answers of some of my peers, if it turned out I liked their answers.

Comment: You forgot one thing: **votes aren't secret anymore if you disclose them**.

Comment: *This isn't strictly true, moderators can see voting trends*: Is it that the diamond moderators? Or anyone with moderator tools i.e. > 10k? They know if I have downvoted/upvoted their post?? Whoops! I need to be careful then ;) Am removing my DVs from all your posts right now ;)

Comment: @abhitalks: only diamond moderators and Stack Exchange developers can see aggregated voting trends.

Comment: @abhitalks - only those of us with diamonds and then only **trends**. We still can't see individual votes.