# How can moderators help if even they cannot see who placed the votes?

Tags: discussion, support, downvotes, downvote-reason

I have the feeling someone was deliberately downvoting me and started research about what to do.

After reading:

- [What to do when someone deliberately down-votes many of the questions which I have asked?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/310242/3664960)
- [What can I do about getting a sudden flood of revenge downvotes?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252270/36649600)
- [What to do when I feel that someone is stalking me?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269172/what-to-do-when-i-feel-that-someone-is-stalking-me)

I was thinking, that I have only 2 downvotes, so I'm not sure if the "bot" (referring to @Ken White's comment from the first question) will see it as deliberate downvoting or not.

So before asking for moderator attention (referring to @Brent Washburne's comment on the second question) on my 2 only upvoted questions, that got downvotes, how can I see if my assumptions are correct?

How can moderators help if even [they cannot see who placed the votes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275052/can-moderators-see-who-upvoted-downvoted-a-specific-question)?

Comment: 2 downvotes? That's a worry for you? 4 rep points that one upvote on a question negates.

Comment: As long as it stays at 2 downvotes, just ignore it.

Comment: You cannot see that. This is intentional design.

Comment: All answers refer to things I already read (added the links to prove my point). Thanks anyway for all the extra downvotes!

Comment: Not to forget all comments also look at my specific case, but try to read the actual questions, how could moderators have helped in the second question, when it is stated that even they cannot see who downvoted ...

Comment: The title and first sentence probably sent users in the wrong direction, even me. I've added a fresh bit about how moderators can help

Comment: [No.  Votes are secret](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/278098/4320665)

Comment: So actually no one read carefully and just downvoted this question. Why don't people read? Thanks @rene

Comment: @davejal I have the same exact problem and I came here to ask and they down voted before reading the whole question too. I dont even use SO as often anymore now because of the down-voting monsters.

Comment: Yes, you are right. They are so mean

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Those down votes are too far apart in time to be considered malicious.  They will not be detected by the voting reversal script (which someone refers to as The Bot). Two votes is not enough for any human, bot or script to spend time on investigating if something beyond the rules happened. You'll have to live with the burden of two down votes by some strangers on the internet.

Serial down voting looks different:

[image: serial voting]

And no, I didn't report that because I tend to annoy users now and then and this is the price I pay.

Moderators cannot see who down voted but they can see patterns. If they find enough evidence that warrants further investigation they defer the investigation to a Community Manager, an SE employee, who can use extra tools to underpin any suspicion which may include querying the production database.

Comment: http://stuffdutchpeoplelike.com/2011/05/28/dutch-directness/

Comment: well, in case asked about here it's really easy to know who is guilty. It's definitely Tim, [he lost his keys again](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397/165773)... twice

Comment: My question wasn't about how downvotes or when downvotes are considered malicious or my specific case ... but thanks for the info

Comment: @davejal then what is it about exactly? You already know based on links posted in your question that you can't see who downvoted you.

Comment: It was about the comments about a `bot` that can/will help in certain cases and others asking the moderators assistance while even the moderators can't see, so they don't have actual reference to decide